# JSON Cross-Domain Error

Tags: javascript, json, cross-domain

Well guys... I've tried lots to fix this problem, catching some solutions here and in others Sites... But i don't get the solution to this problem!

Well what's the real problem.. It's simple i have this code:

```
    function refreshRadioStats()
{
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.get('http://raphaleao.com/json', function(data){
        var templateStats = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> '+ j_lang[0] +
                            '<marquee><h4><i>'+data.musica_atual+'</i></h4></marquee><br>'+
                            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span> '+j_lang[1]+': <b>'+data.ouvintes_conectados+
                            '</b><br>'+
                            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> '+j_lang[3]+': <b>'+locutor+'</b><br><br>'+
                            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="refreshstadistics" style="width:100%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> '+ j_lang[2] +'</button>';
        $('#resultse').append(templateStats);
    },'json');
}
```

Ok, what's the problem?
The problem is: The script apparently can't acess the website **http://raphaleao.com/json** and for this, doesn't work.
The problem:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://raphaleao.com/json. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'Stack don't allow me to post more than 2 links' is therefore not allowed access.

The script works, because i've tested with other site in **JSON** and works perfectly. I've already put this in **web.config**:

```
<httpProtocol>
       <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

And the same problem, could you guys help me with this?

---

**I've get the fix**
Well, after try some things and @mattferderer opened my mind, i figured out what's going on with all this...

First i've removed the **web.config** side and leave only the *header()* function. Okay first problem fixed (lol);

And than, i've figured out why **$.getJSON()** don't load the informations of other website... It's simple, just add (at least i did it in **PHP**) this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
```

In my case, the page is in format **text/html**, so **$.getJSON()** will not able to load all informations in that page!

Thanks guys and sorry for the terrible english!

Comment: What's your backend? You must be setting the access control origin incorrectly somewhere, or its merging the values in two different web.configs.

Comment: The target server must provide the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. If it does not, you cannot access the content from the browser.

Comment: What u rly mean @Jack? Cause I'm new in this world, sorry :(

Comment: Ye @Pointy , i've already put an header on **json.php** but the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the access-control-allow-origin from your web.config since the problem is the access-control-allow-origin is being used twice. If you look in your Response Headers it shows this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 14:43:54 GMT
Content-Length: 387
```

Comment: Ye, i forget to do this... Thanks bro!